# Try Java Constant Classes with JUNIT

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4

I have a class with constants that gives me 0 coverage in sonar, I cannot skip this of this class, how can I do the tests of this class with constants?

```
public class Constants {

    public static final String QUERY_SEARCH_PART = "db1;SELECT GF_CUSTOMER_ID,GF_EMAILUSU_DESC,GF_PHONE_ID,GF_CUSTOMER_NAME,GF_GROUP_ID  FROM GJSX.T_GJSX_CUSTOMER ";

    @VisibleForTestings
    public static final String QUERY_SEARCH_PART_CATALOG =" TABLECATALOGO WHERE OPER.G_CONTRACT_ID=TABLECATALOGO.G_CONTRACT_ID ";
    public static final String GF_FIRST_NAME="GF_FIRST_NAME";
    public static final String G_CUSTOMER_ID="G_CUSTOMER_ID";
    public static final String G_COUNTRY_ID="G_COUNTRY_ID";


    public static final String DB1="db1;";

}
```

Comment: Example of the failing test?

Comment: I don't know how make test for this class

Comment: assertThat(G_CUSTOMER_ID, is(equalTo("G_COUNTRY_ID"))?

Comment: This looks like a class I would not consider appropriate to test.

Comment: You can write a test that verifies there is no public constructor.  But I don’t think that will do much for code coverage.